# Move JS code from HTML to source in HEAD section

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem, and I would like you to guide me to solve it if you do not mind ...
In my HTML source code had several pieces of css codes here and there. So I decided to put together into a file called principal.css and do the following in the head section

```
<link href="css/principal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This has worked wonderfully!
My idea was to do the same with the javascript code in my HTML, but it has not worked. This is one of them:

```
$("[data-slider]")
    .each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    $("<span>")
        .addClass("output")
            .insertAfter($(this));
    })
    .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
    $(this)
        .nextAll(".output:first")
            .html(data.value);
    });
```

Is there some special way to do this?
My goal is that the page has the least amount of code, I leave well indented, documented and clean.
Greetings, I will await your answers in!
Please, excuse my english...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap this in $(document).ready(...)

Also, it has unusual indentation. It would probably be better to format it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-slider]").each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        $("<span>").addClass("output").insertAfter($(this));
    }).bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
        $(this).nextAll(".output:first").html(data.value);
    });

});
```

I personally don't like chaining so many commands like this in a row. It might be SLIGHTLY more efficient, but it makes it much more difficult to debug and fix problems. I personally would break the .each() and the .bind() into separate statements. But I suppose it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Excellent!
Do you think your solution will serve me for any JS code in HTML?

Comment: $() means it's jquery code. If you're pulling jquery into separate files, each file has to have this $(document).ready() wrapper, or $(window).load() as mentioned below.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, I find very useful, I will take into account, do you recommend any good books to learn this type of practice with Javascript?

Comment: i never use any books, but there are hundreds of jquery tutorials online. i'm sure you can find a good one easily. or just ask on stackoverflow. if you like my answer, you can mark it as correct. thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'll search, Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3):

[.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

or

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) documentation

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Place your `js` code in a separate `.js` file. Similar to how CSS is also placed in a separate file and then link it to your html file.

like so, in your html file:

```
<script src="somejsfile.js"></script>
```

And yes, you have to wrap your js code in a document.ready function so it can execute when the documents elements are finished loading.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your JS code here
});
```

This is because the browsers `HTML` interpreter reads code from `TOP to BOTTOM`, so if your not setting a `document.ready`, the `JavaScript` will run before any of your `document elements are loaded`.

Answer (score 1):

Head:

```
<head>
  <link href="css/principal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
```

myscript.js

```
$(function() {    
    $("[data-slider]")
        .each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        $("<span>")
            .addClass("output")
                .insertAfter($(this));
        })
        .bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
        $(this)
            .nextAll(".output:first")
                .html(data.value);
        });
});
```

Comment: Its better practice to place the script after the styles are loaded.

Comment: Also your JS code is incorrect. It should start like so: `$(function() {  /* code here */  });`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that if you plan on putting your js code in a separate file which is a good idea.  You should be aware that you will not have to use the...

```
<script>
  //js code

</script>
```

...the script tags in a separate js file.